# D3 examples from bl.ocks.org full of errors, can version be the reason?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am working with D3js.org but I am new to this and I am having some difficulties with it.
I found some very cool examples from [this site](https://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize) but every one of them has some bugs and I can't load on my machine.
I think it is because of the version because most of them are built with d3.v3 or d3.v4 and D3js latest version is now d3.v7. But even if that is the reason, how are they loaded in [here](https://bl.ocks.org/curran/11b02f8917fac66d6fe5) or [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4) ?

Comment: There are many breaking changes from v3 to v4 (a lot of methods were renamed), and a few key changes from v4 through v7 that will also break code. It is hard to think of an example from v3 that would work with v7 without changes

Comment: I am even trying to include all the versions, like: 


`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`
and


`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>`
but it is still not working.

Comment: Why mix versions? You'd still have issues depending on the order you import. Try to get it working with v3 only, once you can replicate the example you can start migrating, *most* changes are fairly easy and straight forward.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, much appreciated. I will look forward to this.

Comment: @AndrewReid, can  I ask you one more question please? I'm having troubles loading real data on my bar chart. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191947/d3-js-how-to-merge-my-real-data-into-a-pie-chart) question I asked yesterday. I want to display my real data that I retrieve from database and make my bar chart dynamic not just static with some data in an array. Can you answer that please?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the examples on blo.cks.org referenced resources which have moved. For this reason (and others) Mike Bostock took the site offline in Dec 2022.

I've moved these examples to [d3og.com](https://d3og.com) and updated the references of the 40k odd examples to get a large majority of them working again.

For examples using the latest version of D3 https://observablehq.com/ is the best resource. However, it's important to note that examples on Observable are not copy/paste JavaScript and have a unique syntax that you will need to acquaint yourself with.

Answer (score 0):

The Observable page is something in addition to d3.js library it is basically an online Workspace where you directly code d3.js on the browser and the changes get reflected.

It’s good when you want to play around and most likely you will find examples in the d3.js version you are looking for.
I would suggest you use the latest version.

For offline development just use a html page and integrate the d3-library and the modules that you need.
Include a JS script where you will do the coding.

I hope this helps to lift the confusion a little.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. 
Okay but it is not working even for offline development. I need this for an actual online website which I am working in, and I wanted to "copy-paste" an actual D3 project and put it on my page but it just appears blank and a bunch of syntax error which everytime I fix one, another one pops up!

Comment: I'm not sure how how to answer on that. 
With out a technical problem to pin it on.
Perhaps a less complex framework like https://www.highcharts.com/ would help you?