# D3.js how to merge my real data into a pie chart

Tags: asp.net, json, d3.js, data-visualization, angular-promise

I am new to D3 and data visualizing and I'm having some troubles loading my real data.
You'll find my code in the below sections.
Right now I have some data stored in an array, and now what I want to do is, store my actual data from my database into pie charts.

Also if I do this :

```
var mydata=d3.json("mydatafile");
console.log(mydata);
```

It shows me all the data I have retrieved from database in a promise array.
Is there any way possible I can get these data and put them in my charts?

The code for my pie chart written in D3js is below:

```js
    var aColor = [
        'rgb(127, 212, 123)', //green
        'rgb(240, 149, 164)', // red
        'rgb(181, 174, 175)' //gray
    ]
    
    var data = [{
        "platform": "Yes",
        "percentage": 87.00
    }, //skyblue
    {
        "platform": "No",
        "percentage": 1.00
    }, //darkblue
    {
        "platform": "N/A",
        "percentage": 17.00
    }]; //orange
    
    var svgWidth = 200,
        svgHeight = 200,
        radius = Math.min(svgWidth, svgHeight) / 2;
    
    var svg = d3.select('#graph1').append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight);
    
    //Create group element to hold pie chart    
    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");
    
    var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function (d) {
        return d.percentage;
    });
    
    var path = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(80)
        .innerRadius(40);
    
    var arc = g.selectAll("arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .sort((a, b) => b.data.percentage - a.data.percentage);
    
    arc.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return aColor[i]; });
    
    var label = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(20)
        .innerRadius(100);
    
    arc.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
            return +d.data.percentage;
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph1"></div>
```

On the other hand as per my backend, I have this project written on asp.net .net framework and I have this function which retrieves all the data on JSON format, which is cool.

```
public JsonResult BarChart()
{
    string query = "select  e.ProjectName,cyn.Name From Events e left join ConstYesNoes cyn on cyn.ID = e.ApproveId";
    IEnumerable<BarChartsViewModel> ListResults = db.Database.SqlQuery<BarChartsViewModel>(query).ToList();
    return Json(ListResults.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, ApprovedId = x.ApprovedId, ID = x.ID, ProjectName = x.ProjectName }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: You want to use `d3.json("url").then(function(data) { /* visualization code that uses 'data' (the parsed json) here */ })`, if I read your question right. Most simply that would be placing all your code in the d3.json then function and removing the hard coded data.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qodt0zxe/) ? It's still not working though and it just "deletes" my svg.

Comment: At a glance, yes (though you do not need the "var data = " before d3.json). The caveat being your file needs to be a valid url (the fiddle does not contain such a url) and the json file would need to have the correct properties for each item - if you can post a link to it I can demonstrate a solution.